# Error en apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un archivo donde las personas registran una tarea y presionan un botón de enviar y lo envía a un repositorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay varias personas y cuando lo envían en un horario diferente funciona con normalidad pero si lo envían al mismo tiempo se reemplaza un valor por otro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el valor no se reemplace si lo envío al mismo tiempo?

Esta es la función.

```
function CopiarYBorrarSinValidacion(fila){
  const celda0 = "A"+fila;
  const celdahora = "B"+fila;
  const celda1 = "C"+fila;
  const celda2 = "D"+fila;
  const celda3 = "E"+fila;
  const celda4 = "F"+fila;
  const celdanumero = "G"+fila;
    let rangoOrigen = panel.getRange(fila,1,1,7);
    let rangoBorrar = panel.getRange(fila,2,1,6);
    let azar = Math.random()*5;
    var rangoDestino = repositorio.getRange(repositorio.getLastRow()+azar,1);
    var resetFormat = panel.getRange("B119:G119")
    rangoOrigen.copyTo(rangoDestino,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    repositorio.getRange(repositorio.getLastRow(),8).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    rangoBorrar.clearContent();
    resetFormat.copyTo(rangoOrigen,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Las preguntas tienen que estar en español. Dale a [edit](/edit) para traducirla, siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben de incluir un [mcve]. En otras palabras, el código incluido está incompleto, por ejemplo falta la declaración de `panel` y  `repositorio` (quizás faltan más cosas).

Comment: Por otro lado ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer tu scrípt? ¿porqué usas un número aleatorio para la fila del rango destino?

Comment: Hola @Rubén se que no es lo ideal, pero podría hablar contigo por llamada ya que me es difícil describir mi problema.

Comment: @JhonMondragon En mi perfil está la liga a mi perfil en Codementor. A través de esa plataforma es donde ofrezco ayuda a través de videollamadas.

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo Jhon? @Jhon Mondragon

Answer (score -1):

getDocumentLock()   Obtiene un bloqueo que evita que cualquier usuario del documento actual ejecute simultáneamente una sección de código.

getScriptLock()     Obtiene un bloqueo que evita que cualquier usuario ejecute simultáneamente una sección de código.

getUserLock()       Obtiene un bloqueo que evita que el usuario actual ejecute simultáneamente una sección de código.

adjunto link documentación detallada.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getScriptLock()